# If I reinstall qemu on my machine will all my vm data be deleted? Is there anyway that I can preserve my VM data?

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, virt-manager

I'm having some issues with qemu. For some reason `libvirtd.service` does not initialise during startup even though it's enabled in systemctl. I have to manually enter the

```
sudo systemctl start libvirtd.service
```

at boot and then my virtual manager works.

After that I run

```
sudo systemcctl status libvirtd.service
```

to find that the `libvirtd-tcp.socket` and `libvirtd-tls.socket` are not running. Even manually starting them with `systemctl` does'not work. I have decided to reinstall all qemu packages, but if possible, WITHOUT LOSING MY VM's data.

Comment: Always backup your data. Without knowing what is causing the problem, it is hard to say reinstall will fix your problem. Having said all that, reinstalling `qemu` **should not** delete your VM data. **No one can be sure.** If you care about your VMs, **back them up!**

Comment: Have you looked into what `libvirtd-tcp.socket` and `libvirtd-tcp.socket` do? There is a chance you either don't need it or you need to configure it in `/etc/libvirt`.